# google's embedded player conflicts with jquery's fadein method on chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the `mask` element which occupies all window space and has gray color. This element is faded in with jQuery's fade in method. I also have youtube embedded video on the page. However, the mask is not renrendered until I open Developers tools in Chrome and select and node element. It is working in Firefox but leaves embedded video unshaded. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Vgb/) the jsFiddle to demonstate the problem (click `Run` to witness the problem) and the code:

HTML

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gLa3H19cPw4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="mask"></div>
```

CSS

```
#mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    width: 1905px; 
    height: 915px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
//Show mask
$('#mask').fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only fix I've found so far is to use the `.show()` function instead.